# Why im getting black window instead of closing it after saving new model to collection?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, backbone.js, bootstrap-modal

Why im getting black window instead of closing it after saving new model to collection? I have tried with hide on model, and data-dissmis and it's not working. Any have some idea how to solve it?

HTML.Twig:

```
<script type="text/template" id="sidebar-template">         
                <div class="list-group">
                    <p class="list-group-item active">Documents</p>
                <% for(var i=0;i<users.length;i++) { %>                      
                    <a class="list-group-item" id="model" data=<%=users[i].attributes.id%>><%=users[i].attributes.title%></a>                                       
                <%};%>
                </div>

        <!-- Button trigger modal -->
        <button type="button" id="modalbutton" class="btn btn-primary">
        New document
        </button>

        <div class="modal fade my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title">New document</h4>
                </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                                Title: <input id="title" type="text">                   
                    </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="button" id="save" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
                </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
            </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
            </div><!-- /.modal -->

    </script>
```

Save function:

```
save: function()
    {       
            this.collection.create({
                    title: $("#title").val(),
            });
            console.log(this.collection);  
            $('.my-modal').modal('hide');      
    },
```

So after save i can do nothing the modal won't hide and i need to refresh my page, im getting this:

[image: So after save i can do nothing the modal won't hide and i need to refresh my page, im getting this]

Comment: Is this a bootstrap modal or what? Please share a [mcve]

Comment: Yes it's a bootstrap model

Comment: It looks like the modal event is being triggered, and the modal overlay is showing correctly, but the modal itself is hidden.  It might be worth examining the computed CSS properties to see if the modal itself is being hidden.